# coudn't upload multipart data in react app using axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

hi I am trying to post a multipart data in my react app using axios, but it's not not getting posted and giving me the error after taking a long time nearly about more then 5 minutes "(failed) net:::err_CONNECTION_RESET, i don't know what is going wrong here, below is the code snippet

**function that makes the reqeuset** :

```
handleClick(event){
let self = this;
    if(this.state.filesToBeSent.length>0){
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file',this.state.filesToBeSent[0][0]);
            let jsonObject = new Object;
        jsonObject.itemId="1262";
        jsonObject.module="Breakfix";
        jsonObject.filename=("yyyyy");
        jsonObject.filepath="c:\\abc\\";
        jsonObject.createdOn=Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000.0);
        jsonObject.createdBy="3";

            formData.append("attachment", JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
        let filesArray = this.state.filesToBeSent;
    axios.post(GLOBAL.uploadFile,
            formData
);
}
else{
 alert("Please upload some files first");
}
}
**code written on express to route the post to the actual API** : 
function uploadFiles(request, response) {
let payload = request.signedCookies['access_token'];
payload.apikey = "d2c-234";
const secret = 'my-secret';
const signed = jwt.sign(payload, secret, {
algorithm: 'HS256',
expiresIn: '7d'
});
let config = {
headers: {'x-auth-token': signed
}
};
let data={}
if(!_.isEmpty(request.body)) {
data = request.body;
}
axios.post("https://abc-myapp.net/serviceManagement/rest/uploadBreakfixImage/",data,config)
 .then(uploadResponse => {
    response.status(200).json(uploadResponse);
 }).catch(function(error) {
   console.error(error.stack);
 });
}
 when putting console on the express side it seems request doesn't have the payload, what am i doing wrong here ??
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't post JSON data along with the file or any other attachment. You can post it as form data to your back end. The form data is passed as a multi-part data to the server with relevant boundaries. Here's a sample code for your reference. You may pass json data along with the formData as key, value pairs like this.

```
let data = new FormData();

data.append('itemId', '1262');
data.append('module', 'Breakfix');
data.append('filename', 'yyyyy');
data.append('filepath', 'c:\\abc\\');
data.append('upload', fileData, fileName)


axios.post(url, data)
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(errors => console.log(errors));
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding !

Comment: Hi @Ravindra, i am stringifying that JSON object, putting all that in a key named "attachment" and then parsing it again in API side using JSON parsor, it's working fine when i am trying to submit the data through POSTMAN client.

Comment: So you mean, you send entire JSON content as a string in a key value pair against the key called attachment. Then check for HTTP headers and post them here. So that I can help you.

Comment: Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Length:196667
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarymCXU9DZi4uU9kQA4
Cookie:access_token='here is my access token'

Comment: hmm, looks ok to me. Are you sure that the same works with the postman. Then compare the headers between the two instances and check for the difference.

Comment: Hi Ravindra, yes i have checked the headers and they are same, sorry for the late response.could you please help me with the same ?

Comment: Could you please try sending the request first using postman client. Then attach a screenshot of that successful request. Then I can take a look.